# Heroku Postgres - How come my production database is working, even though not listed in settings.py - Django?

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, django-models, heroku-postgres

I configured my database in Heroku several months ago so don't remember exact steps I took. I'm using the Heroku-Postgres add-on: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql

I have a `DATABASE_PASS` listed as a config var in Heroku. And I have a config var for `DATABASE_URL`

In my `settings.py` file I only have the following as it relates to my database. Why is my app still working in production on Heroku if `DATABASES` variable is referring to localhost only?

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'my_dev',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DATABASE_PASS'),
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5410',
    }
}
```

The Heroku-Postgres documentation states the following:

> The value of your app’s DATABASE_URL config var might change at any time. You should not rely on this value either inside or outside your
>   Heroku app.

Am I doing something wrong? Should I not rely on `DATABASE_URL` as a config var?

Additional Detail - I am using the `django-heroku` pip package.

Comment: Wild guess: are you using something like [`django-heroku`](https://pypi.org/project/django-heroku/)?

Comment: I am, since I am using `django-heroku` can we say that my setup is ok? Or are there better practices then my current setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is my app still working in production on Heroku if `DATABASES` variable is referring to localhost only?
>
> Additional Detail - I am using the `django-heroku` pip package.

[`django-heroku`](https://pypi.org/project/django-heroku/) does quite a lot, including setting up your database from the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable automatically:

> This will automatically configure `DATABASE_URL`, `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, WhiteNoise (for static assets), Logging, and Heroku CI for your application.

Comment: So as far as you can see, as long as I'm using `django-heroku` there is no issue with my current setup - even for production?

Comment: Well there could be issues in other parts of your config file, but as far as databases go you should be fine.